# How to check a value in which column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a address table like this

```
City  Area  ID
 AA    BB   1
 CC    DD   2 
 EE    FF   3 
 GG    HH   4
```

I need to extract the ID when I got a name.
However, I don't know the name is a City name or Area name.
So I want to use conditional check the name in City or Area and then extract the ID
I have tried this method, but it was not run for me.

By the way the name is a string.
Ex. name = "AA"

```
if name in df.City:
  ID = df[df["City"] == name]["id"]
elif name in df.Area:
  ID = df[df["Area"] == name]["id"]
```

Any other good solution?

Comment: Why didn't it work?

Comment: I am voting to close the question given it is not clear enough and does not contain enough information to generate a MVE nor understand the error and reproduce it.

Comment: the name is string, and it can not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

`.values` will give you an array therefore your if statement can be true,
but simply the id would return a series object - I guess you only want the number 1 or 2... therefore if you take the `.max()`, that will give you the number also if you pass a name that is not in there it will be an empty object and should not fail (unlike you did it with `iloc`)

```
if name in df.City.values:
   ID = df[df["City"] == name]["id"].max()
elif name in df.Area.values:
   ID = df[df["Area"] == name]["id" ].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are use `query` like so:

```
df.query("City==@name or Area==@name")["ID"]
```